# How do you manage connections to mongodb from C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do you manage mongodb connection from c#? close after use(CRUD)? or put the connection open all the time?

to put things in perspective here is my code:

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);            
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();            
MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("UsersDb");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoClient](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#mongoclient-class) is added to the driver since 1.7, to manage replica set stuff. It's supposed to be singleton and is thread-safe. You can always get MongoServer from it.
You don't need to worry about closing connections. It's managed by the driver.
Refer to the [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/) for more information.